# Camera not staying on nurbs path

Tags: camera, keyframes, constraints, nurbs-surface

my camera won't stay exactly on the nurbs path (there's a small space between them) and then it randomly jumps onto it near the end. I've checked for any rogue keyframes, cleaned keyframes and made sure the camera starts exactly on the path using alt G.  Not sure what else to do..

Can anyone help with this?

Best, Dan

Comment: The camera might be under the influence of some constraint or other such as a "Track to" constraint.
Try this - Clear all animation on the camera and remove it's path constraint and any other  constraint, if there is any.
Make an empty follow the path and then parent the camera to the empty.
Your camera is then free to be rotated and moved about whilst still following the path.  It will also work smoothly with a 'Track-to'  constraint should that be required.

Comment: Further to the above... Make sure the Path and Empty share precisely the same origin point when setting them up. (use SH-S)

Comment: An example for the comments above - 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71486/camera-jitter-when-circling-around-object/71518?noredirect=1#comment124472_71518

Comment: maybe share your camera + curve: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks Edge 3d. There are various constraints on the camera and I've spent a few days settings up all the keyframes so can't really delete all that and start again although I've noticed that the bump happens where there are no keyframes. I do remember making some adjustments in the graph editor although now for some reason , I can't see any curves. Everything is flat, even though I've set most of the keyframes to bezier. I'm wondering if there's a slight alteration I made accidentally but even if so I'm unable to see/rectify it as I can't see anything but flat lines in the graph editor!

Comment: p.s. I tried taking off all the constraints and the bump still happens

Comment: p.s.s.  I just re-created the same problem in a new project where the only keyframes are beginning and ending of the path and it still jumps off near the end

Comment: If you have to use keyframes on the camera and have it follow a path at the same time, the Empty parent for the camera would be the way I'd go.  If you can't resolve this, @Moonboots' suggestion to post your Blend file up and let him (or others) look at it, would be an almost certain cure.

Comment: I wonder if this might help... - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176336/how-do-i-turn-on-path-influence-while-keeping-the-objects-position/176653#176653 - Your camera could be the green cube, coming and going onto and off a path smoothly?